# Weight gradients not mirrored in weight paint mode?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, mirror

I am currently weight painting my mesh and would like to take advantage of the x-mirror functionality to make things consistent. The mesh is symmetrical and the bones are correctly named with the proper L/R suffix. My problem is that while the x-mirror option works with normal brush strokes, it does not seem to work with weight gradient strokes (hold alt or ctrl+alt while making the stroke). Is this simply a problem with Blender or am I missing something that may be keeping it from working properly...?

Comment: I'm sure gradient strokes are not working with x-mirror with the current version of blender.

Comment: Ah, thank you for confirming that. It's unfortunate that it is not working, since I really prefer to the consistency and smoothness that the gradient strokes allow.